# How can i make my text float around a div in react-native?

Tags: css, react-native

[image: wrapped text around div]

Above link is the screenshot of what i'm trying to achieve. I used properties like float, shape-outside, clip-path which worked fine for react. But in react-native float and shape-outside properties aren't supported. Any workaround to achieve the same result for react native app ?

Comment: The image is great, but we need the related code so that we can assis you in finding the error. (thx)